# old container converted in flexbox style

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The old centering method using a container div with a fixed width and margin: 0 auto;

How i can "converted" into a more "modern" way? Because when i use it it centers all elements inside the container not only the container itself, and don't apply the flex-direction property.

EX:

```
<head>
<style>
 .container {
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<section>
<div class="container">

</div>
</section

</body>
```

Comment: `Because when i use it it centers all elements inside the container not only the container itself`--> are you sure?

Comment: you only set max-width, so the div shrinks on itself and centers. no flex-basis nor width is applied to it. Mind that it is a flex child now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the styles for `section` and `.container` like so:

```
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

`justify-content` has a few really useful settings. In your case `center` does the trick. You had `flex-direction: row;` which is fine, but that is the default value for flex direction so you can omit that rule.

A `max-width` on the `.container` so it is not as wide as the flex `section` will now produce the centering effect, just remove the `margin: 0 auto` rule.

Comment: Yes but i still need to assign the display: flex to .container, i thought it will make the childrens inside .container flex-direction row too.

Comment: @GrecA you certainly can apply `display: flex` to the `.container` div and any other flexbox configuration but those styles only apply to the layout of elements inside the `.container` element. Your question appears to only ask how to convert the old `margin: 0 auto` approach to flexbox approach and that is what I put in the answer here.

Comment: Awesome! Mark mine as the answer if that is what helped you get it right.